# How to search for a specific character in an array and delete it accordingly

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to make a function that will delete "negative" responses in a magic 8-ball application. I'm trying to delete any elements of the response array that have the word "no" in them but I don't want to delete responses that include "now" or "not".

```js
const responses = [
  "It is certain",
  "It is decidedly so",
  "Without a doubt",
  "Yes, definitely",
  "You may rely on it",
  "As I see it, yes",
  "Most likely",
  "Outlook good",
  "Yes",
  "Signs point to yes",
  "Reply hazy try again",
  "Ask again later",
  "Better not tell you now",
  "Can't predict now",
  "Concentrate and ask again",
  "Don't count on it",
  "My reply is no",
  "My sources say no",
  "Outlook not so good",
  "Very doubtful"
]

const negativeResponseDeleter = () => {
    let splitTracker = 0
    let holdingArray = []
    for (i = 0; i < responses.length; i++) {
        holdingArray = responses[i].split(" ")
        if (holdingArray.includes("no")) {
            
        }
                
    } 
}

console.log(negativeResponseDeleter())
```

Above is the code I have so far but I keep running into roadblocks, wondering what the best way to go about this would be.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the words in `words` and inverse the condition (if any of the words in the response *don't* contain no, add it to the array) then return the array.

```js
const responses = [
  "It is certain",
  "It is decidedly so",
  "Without a doubt",
  "Yes, definitely",
  "You may rely on it",
  "As I see it, yes",
  "Most likely",
  "Outlook good",
  "Yes",
  "Signs point to yes",
  "Reply hazy try again",
  "Ask again later",
  "Better not tell you now",
  "Can't predict now",
  "Concentrate and ask again",
  "Don't count on it",
  "My reply is no",
  "My sources say no",
  "Outlook not so good",
  "Very doubtful"
]

const negativeResponseDeleter = () => {
    let holdingArray = []
    for (i = 0; i < responses.length; i++) {
        const words = responses[i].split(" ")
        if (!words.includes("no")) {
            holdingArray.push(responses[i])
        }
                
    } 
    return holdingArray
}

console.log(negativeResponseDeleter())
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) that tests to see if a string contains "no" surrounded by word boundaries (`\b`). Then use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to return only those strings that don't pass the test.

```js
const responses=["It is certain","It is decidedly so","Without a doubt","Yes, definitely","You may rely on it","As I see it, yes","Most likely","Outlook good","Yes","Signs point to yes","Reply hazy try again","Ask again later","Better not tell you now","Can't predict now","Concentrate and ask again","Don't count on it","My reply is no","My sources say no","Outlook not so good","Very doubtful"];

const re = /\bno\b/;

const output = responses.filter(response => {
  return !re.test(response);
});

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array filter with a regex that looks for word boundaries:

```js
const responses = [
  "It is certain",
  "It is decidedly so",
  "Without a doubt",
  "Yes, definitely",
  "You may rely on it",
  "As I see it, yes",
  "Most likely",
  "Outlook good",
  "Yes",
  "Signs point to yes",
  "Reply hazy try again",
  "Ask again later",
  "Better not tell you now",
  "Can't predict now",
  "Concentrate and ask again",
  "Don't count on it",
  "My reply is no",
  "My sources say no",
  "Outlook not so good",
  "Very doubtful"
];

const negativeResponseDeleter = () => {
    let holdingArray = responses.filter(str => !/\bno\b/.test(str));
    console.log(holdingArray)
}

negativeResponseDeleter();
```

Output:

`['It is certain', 'It is decidedly so', 'Without a doubt', 'Yes, definitely', 'You may rely on it', 'As I see it, yes', 'Most likely', 'Outlook good', 'Yes', 'Signs point to yes', 'Reply hazy try again', 'Ask again later', 'Better not tell you now', "Can't predict now", 'Concentrate and ask again', "Don't count on it", 'Outlook not so good', 'Very doubtful']`

Answer (score 0):

Or solution which filters array using regex with the shortest syntax:

```js
const responses = [
  'It is certain',
  'It is decidedly so',
  'Without a doubt',
  'Yes, definitely',
  'You may rely on it',
  'As I see it, yes',
  'Most likely',
  'Outlook good',
  'Yes',
  'Signs point to yes',
  'Reply hazy try again',
  'Ask again later',
  'Better not tell you now',
  "Can't predict now",
  'Concentrate and ask again',
  "Don't count on it",
  'My reply is no',
  'My sources say no',
  'Outlook not so good',
  'Very doubtful',
];

const output = responses.filter(elem => !/(no)\b/g.test(elem));

console.log(output);
```